# How to interpret comma separated union/intersection of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do I interpret this:
$$ A_1,A_2 \cup A_3 \cap A_5,A_6 $$

This is what I've done:

- $ A_1 \cup A_3 \cap A_5 $
- $ A_1 \cup A_3 \cap A_6 $
- $ A_2 \cup A_3 \cap A_5 $
- $ A_2 \cup A_3 \cap A_6 $

Is this correct and have I covered everything?

Comment: Even the expressions $X\cup Y\cap Z$ are ambiguous without parentheses (although some would assume that in their absence, the intersection has higher precedence than the union, in analogy with multiplication and division).

Comment: @MPW So do the intersection first, and then the union? E.g. $ A_1 \cap A_5 \cup A_3 $

Comment: Beats me. I've never seen this notation. I'm just pointing out that it is all very ill-defined without some predetermined convention.